# Connectivity of Neo4j with Hive Table

Tags: mapreduce, neo4j, hive

Hi I have a hive table like below:

```
EmpName | ID | dept | sal
  A1      01   IT     100
  B1      02   IT     200
  C1      03   CS     500
```

I want to create neo4j nodes directly from hive table..Is it possible....
Appreciate any ideas in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Check out our CSV import page:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/